# gst_element_class_get_pad_template does not return pud_template

Tags: gstreamer

I want manualy link tee and autovideosink but
Can't get pad template with gst_element_class_get_pad_template:

```
data->video_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("videopipeline");
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data->video_pipeline),udpsrc,rtph264depay,avdec_h264,/*videorate,* /clockoverlay,tee,/*queue,*/autovideosink,NULL);

  if (!gst_element_link_filtered (udpsrc,rtph264depay,udpsrc_caps)){
      GST_ERROR ("Can't link udpsrc and rtph264depay with caps");
  }

  if (!gst_element_link_many (rtph264depay,avdec_h264,/*videorate,*/clockoverlay,tee,NULL)){
      GST_ERROR ("Can't link many to tee");
  }

    gst_object_unref (G_OBJECT(videorate_src_pad));//Возможно получится ошибка с пямятью
    gst_caps_unref(videorate_caps);///Освобождаем caps


    tee_src_pad_template = gst_element_class_get_pad_template(GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS(tee),"src_1");
    pad_surface_src = gst_element_request_pad(tee,tee_src_pad_template,"src_%d",NULL);
  // pad_surface_src = gst_element_get_request_pad(tee,"src_%d");
   if(!pad_surface_src){
    g_printerr ("Can't obtain request pad src for tee.\n");
   }
   /
    pad_surface_sink = gst_element_get_static_pad(autovideosink,"sink");
    if(!pad_surface_sink){
        g_printerr ("Can't obtain request pad sink for autovideosink.\n");
       }
 if (gst_pad_link (pad_surface_src,pad_surface_sink)!=GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
        g_printerr ("Tee could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref (data->video_pipeline);
        return -1;
    }
    gst_object_unref(pad_surface_sink);
```

why does this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pad template on tee is called "src_%u" (or "src_%d" in 0.10). You'll have to use that as a name instead of "src_1".

For requesting a pad you can use the latter, but only do that if you want your pads with those names instead of automatically chosen names by tee. Letting tee choose names is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that i'm using gst 1.0 instead 0.1 so the src must be like "src_%u" and not "src_%d". Thanks